# How to change dpi and resolution at the same time using imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

i have been referring to some imagemagick forum websites such as [this](https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=24890) for jpg to jpg conversion where I can change a few parameters.

```
magick input.jpg -profile cmykprofile -profile rgbprofile -resize 1042x640 -quality 100 -density 72  output.jpg
```

But the same doesn't work for JPG to PNG or PNG to JPG

```
magick inputcmyk.jpg -profile cmykprofile -profile rgbprofile -resize 1042x640 -quality 100 -density 72 output.png
```

Looking for some tips for this.

Comment: PNG does not support CMYK and quality is not specified by 100. PNG only supports density in units of pixelspercm. But you can specify in units of pixelsperin and it will be converted automatically to pixelspercm. When specifying density you need to specify the -units as well. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#png

Comment: @fmw42, it works